# Mysterious random number - wanting to be the same even after "srand()"

Tags: c++, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rand generating same numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246423/rand-generating-same-numbers)

The following is tried when answering another question on StackOverflow:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main() {
  srand ( time(NULL) );
  cout << (float) rand() / RAND_MAX << endl;
  cout << ((float) rand())  << endl;
  cout << RAND_MAX << endl;
  cout << (float) rand() / RAND_MAX << endl;
}
```

Very strangely, the first output number is always a similar number, either on Windows 7 with cygwin or on Mac with Leopard.

The last number is a good random number from 0 to 1.  If the first `cout` line is commented out, the first printed random number is always a similar value one.

How could that be happening?

Comment: What does 'similar value' mean?

Comment: What is `RAND_MAX` on your system? Post an example of the first three or so values of `rand()` and we should see the problem.

Comment: @liori and @FredOverflow similar means always very close, such as 1448210178, 1448226985, and 1448243792 (on Mac).  RAND_MAX was 32767 on Win 7, 2147483647 on Mac

Comment: That's all what random is about: it can be anything, even the same value several times on different places.

Comment: Similar is very different from the same. It could just be a conincidence.

Comment: @ereOn the thing is that it is **constantly** similar

Answer (score 11):

I have stumbled upon this phenomenon myself in the past. The *first* call to `rand()` in four sequential runs of a test program gave the following output:

```
27592
27595
27598
27602
```

Notice how similar those numbers are? This is because the random number generator is initialized with the current time, and the first result is heavily influenced by that. Similar initial values for `srand` yield similar initial results for `rand`. It's as simple as that.

This similarity is irrelevant if you calculate `rand() % n`, but if you go with the `rand() / m` approach, this is a problem. For example, if you divide `rand()` by 100, you will get the same number 3 times in a row!
Now let's take a look at the *second* result of `rand()` in four sequential runs:

```
11520
22268
248
10997
```

This looks much better, doesn't it? A simple quick-fix is to call `rand()` a few times after seeding and simply ignoring the result.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    rand(); rand(); rand();

    std::cout << rand() / float(RAND_MAX) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: no kidding, Dialecticus and FredOverflow... seems like this is not so widely known... and why won't C++ fix this long after C probably had this similar behavior... or strongly advise using a different function than `rand()`?  for example, PHP advise people using a "better rand", `mt_rand()`

Comment: C++ is fixing it in C++0x, there are new random functions. (Unless they are not in the standard any more). Anyway, one solution is to use a more precise timer and see it with (say) the number of microseconds past the last second...

Comment: The basic problem is that rand() just isn't a very good pseudo random number generator.

Comment: ... and perhaps time(0) isn't a particularly good seed?

Comment: hm... some of the official docs I saw was using `time(NULL)` to seed the random number generator.

Comment: @動靜能量: In C++, the macro `NULL` is defined to be `0`.

Answer (score 8):

`rand()` function in VS2008 returns this: `return ((current_value = current_value * 214013 + 2531011) >> 16) & 0x7fff;`. This current_value you set with srand. This function is such that it will return similar pseudo random numbers for similar seeds, and there is no help about it. The problem is that those bits that are the most random in first call are eaten up with >> 16 part. To workaround the problem just roll it a few times (`rand(); rand();`).